# Gernerate all the possible undirected graphs

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, graph

What is an efficient solution to generate *all* the possible graphs using an incidence matrix?
The problems is equivalent of generating all the possible binary triangular matrix. 
My first idea was to use python with itertools. For instance, for generating all the possibile 4x4 matrix

```
for b in itertools.combinations_with_replacement((0,1), n-3):
    b_1=[i for i in b]
    for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement((0,1), n-2):
        c_1=[i for i in c]
        for d in itertools.combinations_with_replacement((0,1), n-1):
            d_1=[i for i in d]
```

and then you create the matrix adding the respective number of zeroes..
But this is not correct since we skip some graphs...

So, any ideas?
Perhaps i can use the isomorphism between R^n matrix and R^(n*n) vector, and generate all the possibile vector of 0 and 1, and then cut it into my matrix, but i think there's a more efficient solutions.

Thank you

I add the matlab tab because it's a problem you can have in numerical analysis and matlab.

Comment: I guess what you really want are all simple graphs, i.e. no loops or double edges. You should try your isomorphism approach, but using: `n-by-n` strictly upper triangular matrices containing only zeros or ones `<=>` `{0,1}^(n*(n-1)/2)`. You could interpret `{0,1}^(n*(n-1)/2)` as binary representations of the numbers from `0` to `2^(n*(n-1)/2)-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example solution using `numpy` that generates all simple graphs:
It first generates the indices of the upper triangular part `iu`. The loop converts the number `k` to it's binary representation and then assigns it to the upper triangular part `G[iu]`.

```
import numpy as np

n = 4
iu = np.triu_indices(n,1) # Start at first minor diagonal
G = np.zeros([n,n])

def dec2bin(k, bitlength=0):
    return [1 if digit=='1' else 0 for digit in bin(k)[2:].zfill(bitlength)]

for k in range(0,2**(iu[0].size)):
    G[iu] = dec2bin(k, iu[0].size)
    print(G)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want *lower* triangular matrices, and that *the diagonal needs not be zero*. The code can be easily modified if that's not the case.

```matlab
n = 4; %// matrix size
vals = dec2bin(0:2^(n*(n+1)/2)-1)-'0'; %// each row of `vals` codes a matrix
mask = tril(reshape(1:n^2, n, n))>0; %// decoding mask
for v = vals.' %'// `for` picks one column each time
    matrix = zeros(n); %// initiallize to zeros
    matrix(mask) = v; %// decode into matrix
    disp(matrix) %// Do something with `matrix`
end
```

Each iteration gives one possible matrix. For example, the first matrices for `n=4` are

```matlab
matrix =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0

matrix =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1

matrix =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0

matrix =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1
```

Comment: ?? why does the classic matlab trick for the comments (eg: `%//`) does not work in this answer ? nevermind ... they work now. Don't know what was wrong.

Comment: @Hoki It didn't work automatically because there are two language tags in the question, I guess. I had to add `<!-- language-all: lang-matlab -->` to make it work

Comment: Thanks, I was coming to that conclusion and looking at your edit confirmed it. _Really whish they would fix the Matlab prettify_

Comment: @Hoki I don't think it's related to how Matlab is prettified. If there are two languages tags, the system probably doesn't know which one to choose